# How to limit the number of calls of celery task

Tags: django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a celery tasks in my project. How can I limit the number of calls of tasks?
For example:

```
@shared_task(base=Singleton, name="load_stocks", auto_retry=[RequestException, NewConnectionError],max_retries=2, queue="products")
def load_stocks():
    return True
```

The task is called from views.py My task receives data about the prodicts stocks in the store via the API and saves them to the database. The user can call this task every minute and it loads the server.
How can I limit the number of times the task is able to work. For example, I want the task cannot be called more than 1 time per hour or 1 time per 3 hours?

Comment: Have you check: `rate_limit`  here https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html ?